# Finding records where sum of count() from two different relations is atleast 2

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create an SQL query that will return the names of non-captain players that have at least 2 fans.

My difficulty is that the fans are split into favourite teams and favourite players, so I have to count the players that are favourited as a team and individually.

Here is what i've come up with, but it doesn't return the correct records:

```
select players.name
from players
-- join relevant relations
join teams
on teams.name = players.team
join favplayers
on players.name = favplayers.player
join favteams
on players.team = favteams.team
-- conditions
where players.team <> teams.captain
group by players.name
having (count(favplayers.player) + count(favteams.team)) > 1;
```

Here is the relational model for reference:

[image]

Any ideas?

Output:

```
NAME             COUNT(DISTINCTFAVPLAYERS.FAN) COUNT(DISTINCTFAVTEAMS.FAN)
-------------------- ----------------------------- ---------------------------
Arthurs                      3               1
Becker                       1               1
Bryan                        0               3
Greul                        0               2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's possible to have favourite players who are members of a team that is nobody's favourite (and vice versa), the joins to the "favourite" tables need to be outer joins. Also, the non-captain condition should be on the name of the player, not the name of the team:

```
select players.name
from players
-- join relevant relations
join teams
on teams.name = players.team
left join favplayers
on players.name = favplayers.player
left join favteams
on players.team = favteams.team
-- conditions
where players.name <> teams.captain -- not players.team
group by players.name
having (count(favplayers.player) + count(favteams.team)) > 1;
```

This should correctly return players that are "favourited" more than once, although if you wanted to include a count of the number of times a player was "favourited", the `having` expression would overcount where there was more than one fan for both the player and the player's team - a better expression would be `count(distinct favplayers.fan) + count(distinct favteams.fan)`. Note also that it would include players where a single fan had "favourited" both the player and their team.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the captain condition mistake. I had it right the first time, but somehow made the mistake when I rewrote it. Also, yes, I did consider the potential double counting from favplayers and favteams, but didn't mention it because I already knew there was no overlap in the records, but I  was wondering how to do that anyway, so for thanks for showing that too.

Comment: I just tried changing it to count `(distinct favplayers.fan) + count(distinct favteams.fan)` just to see if I get the same result, but it cuts off two of the records that definitely should have been included. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include some sample data? Alternatively, if you leave the existing condition, but add the `count(distinct` values to the select clause, what results do you see for the two players in question?

Comment: The two records that drop off when using `distinct` are are linked to favteams. It should return four names `Arthurs, Becker, Bryan, Greul`, but `Bryan, Greul` (which are only favourited because they are in favteams) drop off. I'm not sure how to add `count(distinct` values to the select clause.

Comment: Change `select players.name` to be `select players.name, count(distinct favplayers.fan), count(distinct favteams.fan)` .

Comment: As I said before, **"leave the existing condition"** - ie. `having (count(favplayers.player) + count(favteams.team)) > 1`. Your output in the question doesn't include Bryan or Greul.

Comment: OK, try adding `, count(distinct favplayers.fan) + count(distinct favteams.fan)` to the select clause - the results of the new column should be 4,2,3,2. If they are, change the having clause to be `having count(distinct favplayers.fan) + count(distinct favteams.fan) > 1` - that should have been the condition you were using. (You weren't evaluating them separately, were you?)

Comment: Thanks, all fixed now. When you originally posted the `distinct` update I thought you only added the `distinct` and didn't notice the change in columns to .fan for favplayers/favteam.